# ThreadPoolExecutor takes a longer time than threading modile attempted fix

Tags: multithreading

Hello so i created this fix for a problem and i was wondering about a syntax error on line 3 i am getting? Could You all help

import concurrent.futures
import time

def do_task(task_id):
# Simulate some computational work
time.sleep(1)
return f"Task {task_id} completed."

def main():
num_tasks = 10

```
# Using ThreadPoolExecutor to execute the tasks concurrently
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
    # Submit the tasks to the executor
    future_to_task = {executor.submit(do_task, i): i for i in range(num_tasks)}

    # Wait for the tasks to complete
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_task):
        task_id = future_to_task[future]
        try:
            result = future.result()
            print(result)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Task {task_id} failed: {e}")
```

if **name** == "**main**":
main()

I was trying to fix the problem in the title and it did not work? Help i have tried everything i could find but there are no answers